# raspberry pi 4 and camera does not have camera option in raspi-config menu

Tags: picamera

I am trying to configure my rasp camera with raspberry pi 4. However " sudo raspi-config" i don't have the camera option to enable. I tried updating the os and rebooting and the sudo nano /boot/config.txt
Also the terminal shows supported=0 detected=0
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAOwl.jpg)

Comment: What OS? What research have you done?

Comment: There is no longer a camera option, should auto detect. https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=362707